# How do I interpolate values for blank rows column-wise within the same row name, and then copy the interpolated data to the original DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a spreadsheet that gives the statistics of the 2019 World Happiness Report which will be later used in a visualization and linear regression problem (it is a group project and my part is cleaning the data so that there are as few null values as possible).

I am interested only in years including and after 2010. The data for some countries is entirely missing for a particular year (e.g., Ethiopia is missing 2010 and 2011). I would like to predict the missing parameters of those countries (sich as life ladder and log GDP per capita) by interpolation.

The file can be found here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/happiness-report/2019/Chapter2OnlineData.xls

What I have done until now is creating a new DataFrame for each country and trying to interpolate for that country. (The code is below.) Note that dropdata is the DataFrame I created by dropping countries for which too little information is available, such as Oman.

Also, I have manually inserted rows in the original spreadsheet with the country and year (e.g., Ethiopia, 2011) and blank data values.

But the interpolation does not work at all. I keep seeing NaN values, and when printing the DataFrame, the new rows I inserted do not show up at all.

Below is a sample output.

```
Country name  Year  Life Ladder  Log GDP per capita  Social support  \
     Ethiopia  2012     4.561169            7.115237        0.658794   
     Ethiopia  2013     4.444827            7.189737        0.602482   
     Ethiopia  2014     4.506647            7.261595        0.640452   
     Ethiopia  2015     4.573155            7.335052        0.625597   
     Ethiopia  2016     4.297849            7.382929        0.718719   
     Ethiopia  2017     4.180315            7.455834        0.733540   
     Ethiopia  2018     4.379262            7.524517        0.740155   

     Healthy life expectancy at birth  Freedom to make life choices  \
                         55.200001                      0.776308   
                         55.799999                      0.706796   
                         56.400002                      0.693559   
                         57.000000                      0.802643   
                         57.500000                      0.744308   
                         58.000000                      0.717101   
                         58.500000                      0.740343   

     Generosity  Perceptions of corruption  
   -0.036612                        NaN  
   -0.000997                   0.750478  
    0.086612                   0.701800  
    0.118702                   0.567027  
    0.045363                   0.702881  
    0.007519                   0.756899  
    0.043274                   0.799466
```

And the code I used.

```
country_list = dropdata['Country name']
for country in country_list:
    countryDF = dropdata.loc[dropdata['Country name'] == country, :] #Creates a dataFrame for each country.
    countryDF2 = countryDF.iloc[0:20, 0:9]  #We are interested only in the first 9 rows.
    countryDF2.interpolate(method ='values', axis = 0, limit_direction ='both', limit = 3)
```

There are still NaN values despite having done the interpolation in both directions. What's more, I have to copy the interpolated values from each country's DataFrame back to the original DataFrame (which is to be taken as dropdata), for all the rows. Where do I start?

Comment: There are two DataFrames, countryDF and countryDF2, because loc is used on one and iloc on the other.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) only for filtered values by positions, but first add missing rows by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('Chapter2OnlineData.xls')

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Country name'].unique(), 
                                  np.arange(df['Year'].min(), df['Year'].max() + 1)],
                                  names=['Country name','Year'])
df = df.set_index(['Country name','Year']).reindex(mux).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df[df['Country name'] == 'Algeria'].iloc[0:20, 0:9])
  Country name  Year  Life Ladder  Log GDP per capita  Social support  \
28      Algeria  2005          NaN                 NaN             NaN   
29      Algeria  2006          NaN                 NaN             NaN   
30      Algeria  2007          NaN                 NaN             NaN   
31      Algeria  2008          NaN                 NaN             NaN   
32      Algeria  2009          NaN                 NaN             NaN   
33      Algeria  2010     5.463567            9.462701             NaN   
34      Algeria  2011     5.317194            9.471962        0.810234   
35      Algeria  2012     5.604596            9.485086        0.839397   
36      Algeria  2013          NaN                 NaN             NaN   
37      Algeria  2014     6.354898            9.509210        0.818189   
38      Algeria  2015          NaN                 NaN             NaN   
39      Algeria  2016     5.340854            9.541166        0.748588   
40      Algeria  2017     5.248912            9.540639        0.806754   
41      Algeria  2018     5.043086            9.557952        0.798651   

    Healthy life expectancy at birth  Freedom to make life choices  \
28                               NaN                           NaN   
29                               NaN                           NaN   
30                               NaN                           NaN   
31                               NaN                           NaN   
32                               NaN                           NaN   
33                         64.500000                      0.592696   
34                         64.660004                      0.529561   
35                         64.820000                      0.586663   
36                               NaN                           NaN   
37                         65.139999                           NaN   
38                               NaN                           NaN   
39                         65.500000                           NaN   
40                         65.699997                      0.436670   
41                         65.900002                      0.583381   

    Generosity  Perceptions of corruption  
28         NaN                        NaN  
29         NaN                        NaN  
30         NaN                        NaN  
31         NaN                        NaN  
32         NaN                        NaN  
33   -0.229078                   0.618038  
34   -0.204406                   0.637982  
35   -0.195859                   0.690116  
36         NaN                        NaN  
37         NaN                        NaN  
38         NaN                        NaN  
39         NaN                        NaN  
40   -0.191522                   0.699774  
41   -0.172413                   0.758704
```

---

```
def f(x):
    x.iloc[0:20, 0:9] = x.iloc[0:20, 0:9].interpolate(method ='values',
                                                      axis = 0, 
                                                      limit_direction ='both', 
                                                      limit = 3)
    return x

df = df.groupby('Country name').apply(f)
print (df[df['Country name'] == 'Algeria'].iloc[0:20, 0:9])
```

---

```
   Country name  Year  Life Ladder  Log GDP per capita  Social support  \
28      Algeria  2005          NaN                 NaN             NaN   
29      Algeria  2006          NaN                 NaN             NaN   
30      Algeria  2007     5.463567            9.462701             NaN   
31      Algeria  2008     5.463567            9.462701        0.810234   
32      Algeria  2009     5.463567            9.462701        0.810234   
33      Algeria  2010     5.463567            9.462701        0.810234   
34      Algeria  2011     5.317194            9.471962        0.810234   
35      Algeria  2012     5.604596            9.485086        0.839397   
36      Algeria  2013     5.979747            9.497148        0.828793   
37      Algeria  2014     6.354898            9.509210        0.818189   
38      Algeria  2015     5.847876            9.525188        0.783389   
39      Algeria  2016     5.340854            9.541166        0.748588   
40      Algeria  2017     5.248912            9.540639        0.806754   
41      Algeria  2018     5.043086            9.557952        0.798651   

    Healthy life expectancy at birth  Freedom to make life choices  \
28                               NaN                           NaN   
29                               NaN                           NaN   
30                         64.500000                      0.592696   
31                         64.500000                      0.592696   
32                         64.500000                      0.592696   
33                         64.500000                      0.592696   
34                         64.660004                      0.529561   
35                         64.820000                      0.586663   
36                         64.980000                      0.556665   
37                         65.139999                      0.526666   
38                         65.320000                      0.496668   
39                         65.500000                      0.466669   
40                         65.699997                      0.436670   
41                         65.900002                      0.583381   

    Generosity  Perceptions of corruption  
28         NaN                        NaN  
29         NaN                        NaN  
30   -0.229078                   0.618038  
31   -0.229078                   0.618038  
32   -0.229078                   0.618038  
33   -0.229078                   0.618038  
34   -0.204406                   0.637982  
35   -0.195859                   0.690116  
36   -0.194991                   0.692048  
37   -0.194124                   0.693979  
38   -0.193257                   0.695911  
39   -0.192389                   0.697843  
40   -0.191522                   0.699774  
41   -0.172413                   0.758704
```

Comment: Unfortunately the new rows I inserted are simply not displayed because all the cells in the rows (except the country name and year) are NaN. How do you extend the interpolation for those rows as well?

Comment: @Celcomtel - It is weird, for me working nice, NaNs are repalaced, add testing to answer.

Comment: Yes, the NaNs are taken care of if only a few parameters are NaN (as in row 25 and 26 of your results), but nothing is interpolated if a row is entirely blank (e.g., Algeria, 2013/2015). What can be done? Should the values in Algeria, 2013/2015 be manually set to a non-NaN value such as 0 or -1?

Comment: @Celcomtel - Solution was modify with `reindex`, please check it.

Comment: i think the row/column selection is round the wrong way.  Only the first nine required, yes?

Comment: @flashliquid - Yes, first 20 rows, first 9 columns. What do you think round ?

Comment: @jezrael this is from the OPs comment:
countryDF2 = countryDF.iloc[0:20, 0:9]  #We are interested only in the first 9 rows.

Comment: @flashliquid - hmmm, maybe OP explain more.